# Python: Read in specific lines from a file and replace a specific character on those lines and save file

Tags: python, loops, iteration

New to python and can't find the answer for this problem.
I have a file similar to this:

@BNNDSIJHF
ABCDABCDAB
&
*&ABDA&&#

There are four lines of data for an object. There are 1000's of objects in the file, so there are 4*objects in the file. 
I need to replace all the Bs with Xs, but only on line 2 of each object.
Ex.

@BNNDSIJHF
AXCDAXCDAX
&
*&ABDA&&#

Even though the last line of the object has Bs in it, they don't get replaced.
Here's what I've tried:

```
import sys
import os
def open_and_replace(filename):
with open(filename) as read_file:
    temp = open("/tmp/temp.txt","w")
    for index,line in enumerate(read_file,1):
        if index == 2:
            temp.write(line.replace('B', 'X'))
            index=index+4
        else:
            temp.write(line.strip() + "\n")
    temp.close()
os.rename("/tmp/temp.txt",filename)
for file_name in sys.argv[1:]:
open_and_replace(file_name)
```

This replaces the all the B's in the file past line 2. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do all objects start with `@` on the first line?

Comment: No - they vary. Random characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `if index == 2` statement to be `if index % 4 == 2`, and remove the `index=index+4` line.

Comment: Thanks!! That absolutely fixed it! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, if you have a list of lines with no whitespaces

```
[x for x in f.readlines() if x.strip()]
```

such as

```
['@BNNDSIJHF',
 'ABCDABCDAB',
 '&',
 '*&ABDA&&#',
 '@BNNDSIJHF',
 'ABCDABCDAB',
 '&',
 '*&ABDA&&#']
```

You can just use a for loop starting at 2nd line with a step of 4, which is the fixed length of every object.

```
for i in range(1, len(ll),  4):
    ll[i] = ll[i].replace('B', 'X')
```

Then just `'\n'.join` save it back to a file